# Android Studio error when trying to run app

Tags: android, android-studio

I am trying a simple Android app with a WebView to show a local html page.

The project builds OK, but when clicking the run button I get the following error:

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'.
>   com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_05/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 2

What may be causing this error? I have done more complex apps without problems, so I guess it is something related to the html staff.

Comment: check in project module which adj are you using

Comment: `Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'`, this apart of the build. So it did not build correctly. And what are you talking about here: `something related to the html staff.`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just solved my problem doing the following in the build.gradle(Module:app):

I removed the first compile:

```gradle
dependencies {
    // compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:+'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:+'
}
```